# Next.js: How to submit a form, fetch from API and render a new page based fetched data?

Tags: next.js

I am new to Next.js and trying to migrate a CRA.

Almost everything in the app is static but there is a form that when it is submitted, a call is made to the server, and then a new page (a report) is rendered and filled in. The data is dynamic and depends on how the form was filled out.

Besides that, I use the ContextAPI to share this data to multiple components.

I would like to know how to convert this functionality to Next.js. Thanks in advance.